# Get fields from NSArray with CoreData content

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, core-data

I have a table in core data with some fields, I can get the count of records, but I can´t get the values from each field, now I have this code:

```
var request:NSFetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Radar") //my table in core data

let appDelegate:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate)
let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

var results:NSArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)!

println(results.count) //this is the count that i can do
```

I need some more,
Radar have this fields: Descr,Latit,Long
I need get this fields to create an annotation
some like this: results.Descr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to loop your array of results and cast each result as the `NSManagedObject` you retrieved, in you case `Radar`

```
if results.count > 0
{
    for result in results
    {
         if let r = result as? Radar{
             //now you can access the properties of Radar in r
             println(r.descr)
         } else{
             println("Could not cast fetch result to Radar")
         }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thks a lot, save my day